# Generate JAXB classes with equals() from schemas with relative schemaLocation in multiple Maven modules

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a Maven project with 3 modules: `schema`, `gml` and `adress`. schema contains two XSDs: `gmlprofil-1.1.xsd` - a simple GML profile and `adress.xsd` which imports the GML schema using a relative schemaLocation, like so:

```xml
<import schemaLocation="../gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd" namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"/>
```

In both the `gml` module and the `adress` module, I use `maven-jaxb2-plugin` with `jaxb2-basics` in order to generate classes with equals() and hashCode(). The `gml` module works fine, but when running `adress`, I get this error:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; IOException thrown when processing "../gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd". Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\code\gml\gmlprofil-1.1.xsd
```

Fine. A catalog file to the rescue!

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "../gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd" "maven:com.test:schema:jar::!/com/test/schemas/gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd"
```

It looks like the absolute path is resolved OK, but then a MalformedURLException occurs.

```
[DEBUG] Parent resolver has resolved publicId [null], systemId [../gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd] to [maven:com.test:schema:jar::!/com/test/schemas/gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd].
[DEBUG] Resolving systemId [maven:com.test:schema:jar::!/com/test/schemas/gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd] as Maven dependency resource.
[DEBUG] Resolved dependency resource [Dependency {groupId=com.test, artifactId=schema, version=1.0-SNAPSHOT, type=jar, classifier=null, resource=com/test/schemas/gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd}] to resource URL [jar:file:/C:/code/jaxb-test/schema/target/schema-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/test/schemas/gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd].
[DEBUG] Resolved systemId [maven:com.test:schema:jar::!/com/test/schemas/gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd] to [jar:file:/C:/code/jaxb-test/schema/target/schema-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/test/schemas/gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd].
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ maven:com.test:schema:jar::!/com/test/schemas/adress/adress.xsd{8,97}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: maven:com.test:schema:jar::!/com/test/schemas/adress/adress.xsd; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 97; unknown protocol: maven
...
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: maven
```

This is my pom for `adress`:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources</bindingDirectory>
      <episode>true</episode>
      <useDependenciesAsEpisodes>true</useDependenciesAsEpisodes>
      <extension>true</extension>
      <forceRegenerate>false</forceRegenerate>
      <schemaLanguage>XMLSCHEMA</schemaLanguage>
      <strict>false</strict>
      <verbose>false</verbose>
      <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.cat</catalog>
      <args>
        <arg>-npa</arg>
        <arg>-XsimpleEquals</arg>
        <arg>-XsimpleHashCode</arg>
      </args>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
          <version>0.9.5</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
      <schemas>
        <schema>
          <dependencyResource>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>schema</artifactId>
            <resource>com/test/schemas/adress/adress.xsd</resource>
          </dependencyResource>
        </schema>
      </schemas>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I have tried some solutions:

1. Setting the Maven URL as the schemaLocation:

```xml
<import schemaLocation="maven:com.test:schema:jar::!/com/test/schemas/gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd" namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"/>
```

2. Setting an absolute schemaLocation and updating the catalog file accordingly:

```xml
<import schemaLocation="http://test.com/schemas/gml/gmlprofil-1.1.xsd" namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"/>

REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://test.com/schemas" "maven:com.test:schema:jar::!/com/test/schemas"
```

3. Lowering the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` version to 0.9.1. Using this method, I don't even need a catalog file, however I get this error instead:

   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.9.1:generate (default) on project adress: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.9.1:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.9.1:generate: com/sun/tools/xjc/model/Aspect

   This can be resolved by swapping in `-Xequals` and `-XhashCode` instead of `-XsimpleEquals` and `-XsimpleHashCode`.

All three solutions work, but none is perfect. The first two require manipulating the schema, while the third introduces an unwanted dependency on `jaxb2-basics-runtime` in the generated classes. The latter is acceptable but I would greatly appreciate it if anyone knows how to run simpleEquals with my setup.

Comment: A test project can be found [here](http://www.ominousfrogs.com/data/share/jaxb-test.zip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, welcome to my world of pain.

You're surely aware of the [ogc-schema](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) project, right?

The interesting part is actually that catalog even seems to resolved correctly. Not sure what's happening there but here's the solution I've finally found out to work best:

- Compile the absolute URL:

  ```
          <schemas>
              <schema>
                  <url>http://test.com/schemas/adres/adres.xsd</url>
              </schema>
          </schemas>
  ```
- Use a catalog to rewrite

  REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://test.com/schemas" "maven:com.test:schema:jar::!/com/test/schemas"

This is basicallyyour third solution but you don't have to change the schema. Just start from an absolute URL, it will be rewritten by the catalog.

Ah, yes:

**DISCLAIMER** I'm the author of [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin), [jaxb2-basics](/questions/tagged/jaxb2-basics) as well as the [ogc-schema](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) project mentioned above.

By the way, what's so bad about the `jaxb2-basics-runtime` dependency?

Comment: Your proposed solution _does_ work, but `adress.xsd` isn't directly available on a public url, which is why it was put in a schema jar to begin with.

As for the `jaxb2-basics-runtime` dependency, the `gml` module is really a jar dependency that contains the generated classes (with `-XsimpleEquals`) along with utility code for manipulating the geometry. If the regular `-Xequals` is used on `adress.xsd`, the compiler complains that superclasses don't have an `equals(ObjectLocator, ObjectLocator, Object, EqualsStrategy)` method.

Comment: @aznan It does not have to be actually available via this absolute URL. Will be reverted anyway, this is completely virtual.

Comment: @aznan Yes, if you do `-Xequals`, you have to do `-Xequals` consequently everywhere (same for `-XsimpleEquals` etc.). I just don't understand why people have problem with this dependency. One more tiny JAR, what's the problem? But it makes generated methods much better - you can provide strategies etc.

Comment: Huh, I thought I checked if using the virtual url worked, but I guess I didn't. Awesome! Thanks!